# Is there builtin way to use protected AJAX endpoint?

Tags: ajax, rest-api

Usually I declare "protected" endpoints as this. So logged in users can use this endpoint.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```

Is there a way to make it only accessible to administrators (and not other users)?

Comment: Just put a capabilities check in the callback function. Or better yet, use the REST API which has much more robust support for permissions.